# Hover image_rgba Bokeh

Tags: python, image, bokeh, rgba

I'd like to be able to hover over a RGBA image using Bokeh. For this purpose, I'd like to specify a channel as the value when hovering or another data with the same shape. For example, here it follows a minimal example, where I'd like to display a pixel's alpha value on hover, which does not work:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

N = 20
rgba = np.empty((N,N, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        rgba[i, j, 0] = int(i/N*255)
        rgba[i, j, 1] = 158
        rgba[i, j, 2] = int(j/N*255)
        rgba[i, j, 3] = 255

img = np.squeeze(rgba.view(np.uint32))
data = dict(image=[img],
    x=[0],
    y=[0],
    dw=[20],
    dh=[10],
    value=[rgba[:,:,3]])

TOOLTIPS = [
    ("x", "$x"),
    ("y", "$y"),
    ("value", "@value")
]

# must give a vector of images
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_range=(0, 20), y_range=(0, 10), tools='hover,wheel_zoom', tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
p.image_rgba(source=data, image='image', x='x', y='y', dw='dw', dh='dh')
show(p)
```

Is it possible to provide this kind of visualisation with Bokeh?

Comment: Don't you have to `import` anything?

Comment: Included the import, @MarkSetchell. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: It looks like this functionality is now included (as of Bokeh version 1.2.0)

Answer (score 3):

While implementing `Image` hover in Bokeh, I discussed the possibility of supporting `ImageRGBA` hover as well but we were not entirely clear how hover should behave in that case. As of Bokeh 1.0.4, `ImageRBGA` hover in Bokeh is not yet supported but if you file a GitHub issue, I think that could reopen discussion and get this feature implemented.